# Tinting of icons like in the Support NavigationView

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

The **NavigationView** does a **color tinting** on the icons if they colored.
My icon is green and in the NavigationView it is **grey**. How does this work?

I want to do this myself in a other view, but I didn't find how NavigationView do this.

Comment: You need to set your colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark styles. You also need to make sure you are setting your item as checked.

Comment: I want to to do this with another view, not NavigationView. I have a view with my icon, but I want to display the icons in greay instead of the color the icon has.

How can I achieve this? The NavigationView was only an example because they change the color of my icon :-)

So it should be possible, but how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) explains AppCompat tinting of drawables. Is this what you're looking for?

> The Drawable tinting methods added in Lollipop are
>   super useful for letting you dynamically tint assets. AppCompat had
>   its own baked in implementation in the v21 support library and we’ve
>   now extracted that into DrawableCompat in support-v4 for everyone to
>   use. It’s important to know how it works though.
>
> ```
> Drawable drawable = ...;
>
> // Wrap the drawable so that future tinting calls work 
> // on pre-v21 devices. Always use the returned drawable.
> drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
>
> // We can now set a tint 
> DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.RED);
> // ...or a tint list 
> DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, myColorStateList);
> // ...and a different tint mode
> DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
> ```

Or if you just want to tint an ImageView, you can do this:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setColorFilter(...);
```